# kubectl run - How to pass all the ENV variables of the hosting shell to the pod?

Tags: kubernetes, environment-variables, kubectl

It is possible to pass some ENV variables to the pod via the `--env` option of `kubectl run`, for example:

```
kubectl run -ti --rm test --image=busybox --env location=city --env time=morning --namespace default -- sh
```

I would like to send all the present ENV variables to the pod without specifying all of them the via `--env`, especially for those that I might not know the variable name. Is there an way to do so? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
kubectl run -ti --rm test --image=busybox $(printenv | xargs -I % echo '--env' "%" | tr '\n' ' ') --namespace default -- sh
```

Comment: Thanks. I will accept your solution. However, the more I think, it seems that the whole idea of this question was not a good one, considering the possibility for special characters and spaces in the values or names of the variables.